# Next.js: react-color - Warning: Prop `style` did not match

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-color

[image]

I'm using `Next.js` framework & I'm getting a warning when I use `react-color` in my `index.js`.

**Here is `index.js`:**

```
import SketchPicker from 'react-color';

const index = () => {
    return <SketchPicker />
}

export default index;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that error because the `style` prop generated from SSR does not match the client-side one. You could solve it by only loading `SketchPicker` on the client with Next.js dynamic import.

You also need to pass a state  setter to `onChangeComplete`
and state variable to `color` to properly handle the color picking.

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const SketchPicker = dynamic(
  () => import('react-color').then((mod) => mod.SketchPicker),
  { ssr: false }
);

const Index = () => {
    const [color, setColor] = useState();
    const handleChange = (color) => setColor(color);

    return <SketchPicker color={color} onChangeComplete={handleChange} />;
}

export default Index;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide the Color picker initially and it renders on any further user interaction.
Refer [sample code](https://github.com/casesandberg/react-color/issues/743#issuecomment-672249452) here, where it is hidden using `state.displayColorPicker`.